# Modify string representation of data in Python

Tags: python

O would like to modify my data. My function is:

```
 print (str(freq[8:10])[2:-1])
```

I have 2 results like this: `105.00000031 105.0000041`

Can I modify the presentation of this to include newlines like this?:

```
105.00000031
105.00000041
```

[data to normalyze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLumB.jpg)

Comment: ok I'll screenshot this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or, as another alternative,

```
>>> data = '105.00000031 105.0000041'
>>> print('\n'.join(data.split()))
105.00000031
105.0000041
```

Handles irregular spaces gracefully.

Comment: I think this function can help me but I have this error 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @azerty1233456 if `arr` is your 1D array, do `arr_str = str(arr)[1:-1]`. Then execute the second line.

Comment: You need to convert that array representation to a string. Obviously you cannot perform string operations on an array.

Comment: @azerty1233456 Cheers :)

Comment: if I want to did the same with str() ? it's the same syntax ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but if what you want is to take a string and replace all spaces with "\n", you can simply replace.

```
data = '105.00000031 105.0000041'
data.replace(' ', '\n')  # returns the data separed by newlines
data2 = data.replace(' ', '\n')  # saves the data separed by newlines in a new variable
data = data.replace(' ', '\n')  # replaces the original data with the "normalized" one
```

If you might have more complicated patterns (multiple spaces, colons, anything) you should use the re module. Is this the case?

Comment: yeah sometimes I have multiple spaces : for example: 104.998 104.999    105.698       105.        106.64. If I want to have 104.998(then \n)104.999(then\n)105.000.... did it works ?

Comment: Yes this method would work, it replaces all spaces throughout the string with newlines

Comment: Using your string it outputs: '104.998\n104.999\n105.698\n105.\n106.64' which seems what you need. My question was if your data can be like this: 104.998         104.999  105.698   105. 106.64 (an irregular number of spaces beteween the numbers).